# how to run rosjava_tutorial_pubsub?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I might have missed something, but based on the wiki and tutorial of Rosjava, I can not figure out how to run the tutorial code of Rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.

I compiled rosjava with Gradle (earlier have tried to install from Ubuntu repository as well as compiled with Rosmake).

1. There is no run.py in rosjava_bootstrap, so that I cannot use the command from the tutorial: rosrun rosjava_bootstrap run.py <*****> <****>
2. Also, Rosrun won't find any executable from rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.

Any idea or link that can help?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30043/how-to-run-rosjava_tutorial_pubsub?/) by [Ze JI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1235/ze-ji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The run.py script is no longer used since the switch to Gradle. Instead, rosjava_tutorial_pubsub creates an executable jar using Gradle's Application plugin. See the documentation which describes how to execute the Talker and Listener nodes from the pubsub tutorial:

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html#executing-nodes

Also make sure to follow the documentation on installing and building rosjava_core:

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1